# How to convert Procedural JavaScript into OOP where different parts extra tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, oop

I made some code to check the URL if it has a query-string and then if it did using JavaScript add the items into input fields Now the way I have done it works. However because it is more basic I keep having to add more tests to future which just drastically inflates my code. I tried converting to more object oriented method so that my function is same but I can just add a new variable to array so I don't have to keep duplicating the function but it is not working and I'm not entirely sure how come (I'm still new to the object orientated)

I have tried converting it to Object Orientated like such (some of the code I got help with) This is my attempt which did not end up working **note that the code that I am talking about is the in the `function init()`** Note the function `init()` is called above to run it auto on page load to check states of whether there is a query string or not

```
function getUrlVars(urlVariable) {
    var vars = {};
    window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
            if (key === urlVariable) vars[key] = value;
        }
    );

    return vars;
}

function init() {
    var screensize = screen.width;
    var itemQuery = {
        moreBikes:{
            urlVar: getUrlVars("currentbike"),
            selector: '#currentbikes',
            newElement: '<div class=""><input type="text" name="currentbike[]" class="currentbikesadd" value="${morebikes[i]}" ><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>',
            oldElement: '<input type="text" name="currentbike[]" class="currentbike">'
        }     
    }

    if (urlVar) {
        var item = itemQuery[item];
        let urlVaribale = item.urlVar.split('_');
        for (let i = 0; i < item.urlVaribale.length; i++){
            $(item.selector).append(decodeURI(item.newElement))
        }
    } else if (!urlVar) {
         $(item.selector).append(item.oldElement);
    }

}
```

I tried doing something like this however it did not work. (I think it may have to do with missing a viable in `init()` but not too sure. Also in future when I add my other fields as some of them have other checks in place *(see code below for my older code and what i mean have some other fields)*. So How would I go about combining it into one Below is the Older (working) non object oriented version of the code

***this is original version of my code that works***

```
function getUrlVars(urlVariable) {
    var vars = {};
    window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
            if (key === urlVariable) vars[key] = value;
        }
    );
    return vars;
}

function init() {
    var screensize = screen.width;
    var othersocial_p = getUrlVars("kothersocial");
    var othersocialqty_p = getUrlVars("kothersocialqty");
    var morebikes_p = getUrlVars("currentbike");

    //more bikes
    if (morebikes_p['currentbike']) {
        //create the array
        let morebikes = morebikes_p['currentbike'].split('_');
        //loops
        for (let i = 0; i < morebikes.length; i++) {
            $(wrapper_bike).append(decodeURI(`<div class=""><input type="text" name="currentbike[]" class="currentbikesadd" value="${morebikes[i]}" ><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>`))
        }
    } else if (!morebikes_p['currentbike']) {
        $(wrapper_bike).append(`<input type="text" name="currentbike[]" class="currentbike">`);
    }

    //other social media
    if (othersocial_p['kothersocial'] && othersocialqty_p['kothersocialqty']) {
        //create the array
        let othersocial = othersocial_p['kothersocial'].split('_');
        let othersocialqty = othersocialqty_p['kothersocialqty'].split('_');
        if (screensize < 800) {
            //loops the length of the username
            for (let i = 0; i < othersocial.length; i++) {
                $(wrapper_othersocial).append(decodeURI(`<div class="more800 A"><label for="othersocial" id="othersocialmedia">Other - Please specify <br><input name="othersocial[]" class="othersocial addedothersocial" value="${othersocial[i]}" style="margin-bottom:5px;"></label><label for="otherqtys" id="otherqty"> Followers Count: <br>
<input name="otherqty[]" class="otherqtys addothersocquantity" value="${othersocialqty[i]} " style="margin-bottom:5px;" ></label><button style="margin-top:10px;" class="delete">Delete</button><div class="clearfix"></div></div>`));
            }
        } else {
            $(othersocialid).append(`<div class="more800 b"><label for="othersocial" id="othersocialmedia">Other - Please specify <br></label><label for="otherqtys" id="otherqty"> Followers Count: <br></label> <div class="clearfix"></div></div>`);
            //loops the length of the username
            for (let i = 0; i < othersocial.length; i++) {
                $(wrapper_othersocial).append(decodeURI(`<input name="othersocial[]" class="othersocial addedothersocial" value="${othersocial[i]}" style="margin-bottom:5px;"><input name="otherqty[]" class="otherqtys addothersocquantity" value="${othersocialqty[i]} " style="margin-bottom:5px;" ><button style="margin-top:10px;" class="delete">Delete</button></div>`));
            }
        }
    } else if (!othersocial_p['kothersocial']) {
        counter_social++;
        if (screensize < 800) {
            $(othersocialid).append(`<div style="display:inline-block;width: 100%;;" class="less800">
<label for="othersocial" id="othersocialmedia">Other - Please specify <br><input type="text" name="othersocial[]" id="othersocial" class="othersocial"></label>
<label for="otherqtys" id="otherqty"> Followers Count: <br><input type="text" name="otherqty[]" id="otherqtys" style="margin: 10px 0"></label> <div class="clearfix"></div></div>`)
        } else {
            $(othersocialid).append(`<div class="more800"><label for="othersocial" id="othersocialmedia">Other - Please specify <br><input type="text" name="othersocial[]" id="othersocial" class="othersocial"></label><label for="otherqtys" id="otherqty"> Followers Count: <br><input type="text" name="otherqty[]" id="otherqtys" style="margin: 10px 0"></label> <div class="clearfix"></div></div>`)
        }
    }
}
```

What the code is basically doing is checking to see if the query string has the array relating to the variable that ends in `variable_p[''].split('_')` and is splitting up them as i saved them like that as an array in query string.
Then this is where it splits for the items that have 1 item:
like more bikes it is going straight into the `for loops` the output the value where it will go to check if there isn't a value in the query string and then just input an empty input field
However for the splits that have 2 items:
first check for the screen size as depending on screen size it will show up slightly different. So then depending on the screen size it will show the different layouts of the exact same information just in different order.
Else like before it will show empty inputs but also depending on screen size have slightly different layout.

Is there a way to make this into one object orientated function or should i split the function into those with 2 variables and the screen-size split or is there a way to test it and just do it as one simple function? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This line, `var item = itemQuery[item];`, might be the root of the problem. Did you mean `var item = itemQuery.moreBikes;` There are other errors, too; for example,  `item.urlVaribale` is undefined.

Comment: oh, I knew there were errors i'm still learning this so it makes sense. Do you know how i could possibly fix the `var item = itemQuery[item]` also yea i see what you mean i declared the `urlVaribale = item.urlVar` so then i should've just called in `urlVaribale` since `item.urlVaribale` doesn't actually exist